# How to populate adapter with a List of decimal through Simple Spinner Item C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, android-adapter

How to populate adapter with a List of decimal through Simple Spinner Item ?

```
   private async void GetCheckUserStore(string uname) {

        StoreNameRepository<List<decimal?>> repo = new StoreNameRepository<List<decimal?>>();
        List<decimal?> result = await repo.GetCheckUserStore(uname);

        if(result!= null) {

         //   ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, Convert.ToInt32(result));
         //spinner_storelist.Adapter = adapter;

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would convert that list of decimal values to a list of string values and then use the same something like this :

```
private async void GetCheckUserStore(string uname) {

    StoreNameRepository<List<decimal?>> repo = new StoreNameRepository<List<decimal?>>();
    List<decimal?> result = await repo.GetCheckUserStore(uname);
    List<string> stringResult = result.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
    if(result!= null) {

     ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, stringResult);
     spinner_storelist.Adapter = adapter;

    }
```

Do not forget to add the following namespace :

`using System.Linq;`

Comment: Thanks man! I thought that it will be a decimal format through the spinner. you make it decimal to string first. Thanks